# Store 2 different encoded data in a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encoding

I have 2 types of encoded data

1. *ibm037* encoded -  a single delimiter variable - value is `@@@`
2. *UTF8* encoded - a pandas dataframe with 100s of columns.

Example dataframe:

```
Date Time

1    2
```

My goal is to write this data into a python file. The format should be:

```
@@@  1    2
```

In this way I need to have all the rows of the dataframe in a python file where the 1st character for every line is `@@@`.

I tried to store this character at the first location in the pandas dataframe as a new column and then write to the file but it throws error saying that two different encodings can't be written to a file.

Tried another way to write it:

df_orig_data = pandas dataframe,
Record_Header = encoded delimiter

```
    f = open("_All_DelimiterOfRecord.txt", "a")
        for row in df_orig_data.itertuples(index=False):
            f.write(Record_Header)
            f.write(str(row))
    f.close()
```

It also doesn't work.

Is this kind of data write even possible? How can I write these 2 encoded data in 1 file?

**Edit:**

```
StringData = StringIO(
    """Date,Time
1,2
1,2
"""
)

df_orig_data = pd.read_csv(StringData, sep=",")

Record_Header = "2 "
```

```py
    f = open("_All_DelimiterOfRecord.txt", "a")
    for index, row in df_orig_data.iterrows():
        f.write(
            "\t".join(
                [
                    str(Record_Header.encode("ibm037")),
                    str(row["Date"]),
                    str(row["Time"]),
                ]
            )
        )
    f.close()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to enhance your [mcve]. A code for typical data in `df_orig_data` e.g. `import pandas as pd; df_orig_data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':(0,2,3,0),'Time':(2,0,3,2)})` and for `Record_Header`.

Comment: Check the following code snippet: `Record_Header = '@@@'; for index, row in df_orig_data.iterrows(): print('\t'.join( [Record_Header, str(row['Date']), str(row['Time'])]))`

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you so much for the suggestions and the solution. I tried with this approach but the problem is that Record_Header is in ibm037 format and df_orig_data is a UTF-8 pandas dataframe. Please check the 'Edit' section in the post above. The problem occurs when I try to write 2 different encoding data to a file.

Comment: Can you include the value of `Record_Header` and `df_orig_data` ? It's significantly more work for us to guess what it should look like, and including your data results in answers that are more likely to be helpful.

Comment: @NickODell please find the edits in the 'Edit section'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing the encoding yourself, and writing a bytes object to the file. This isn't a situation where you can rely on the built-in encoding do it.

That means that the program opens the file in binary mode (`ab`), all of the constants are byte-strings, and it works with byte-strings whenever possible.

The question doesn't say, but I assumed you probably wanted a UTF8 newline after each line, rather than an IBM newline.

I also replaced the file handling with a context manager, since that makes it impossible to forget to close a file after you're done.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
StringData = io.StringIO(
    """Date,Time
1,2
1,2
"""
)

df_orig_data = pd.read_csv(StringData, sep=",")
Record_Header = "2 "


with open("_All_DelimiterOfRecord.txt", "ab") as f:
    for index, row in df_orig_data.iterrows():
        f.write(Record_Header.encode("ibm037"))
        row_bytes = [str(cell).encode('utf8') for cell in row]
        f.write(b'\t'.join(row_bytes))
        # Note: this is an UTF8 newline, not an IBM newline.
        f.write(b'\n')
```

Comment: Perfect. This seems to work.